# laravel 5.5 - POST route go to GET route

Tags: php, vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I have this route `Route::post('/profiles', 'ProfilesController@store')`, but always it suppose to call the function `store()`. Everything works fine in local server.

However, it always call `index()` when I upload everything in production server. I did not get any error at all. I believe for some setting reason, `Laravel` block the `post` and divert it to `get` instead.

I am calling the route from with in the `due component`.

I have added `csrf_token` in my `bootstrap.js`:

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

in my `vue` component:

```
axios.post('/profiles/', self.profile)
```

Am I missing something?

Do I have to explicitly add `csrf_token` to the header even after all the setting at `bootstrap.js`?

Comment: It's possibly a server configuration issue. Either the webserver is not accepting post or php.ini is not set correctly.

Comment: But I can do user sign up. Isn't that means POST request don't have issue?

Comment: Post your routes file. Lets see if there is a collision somewhere.

Comment: The same routes file works perfectly on local server. So I don't think is the routes files.

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash on the post: `axios.post('/profiles', self.profile)`

Comment: Bro you save my life! Please change it to answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested :)

Try removing the trailing slash on the post:

```
axios.post('/profiles', self.profile)
```